# using logcat outside android world

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, logcat

I'm windows c# developer and I works sometime with android, just for fun, and I found logcat really useful, so I've been looking around for a while how send log to logcat, but I 've found nothing, I dunno where find protocol ecc.

I like to send text to logcat, just like NLog (http://nlog-project.org/), to use logcat as
log viewer, since I haven't found anything such as NLog to log into logcat

so where I can find some info how send in c# some log?

alternative is welcome

thanks

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by "how send log to logcat"? Also, what have you tried?

Comment: Are you just trying to Log something using c#?

Comment: Are you just trying to Log something using c#? the problem is this I dunno how send a log to logcat... se last time modify to my answer :)

Answer (score 1):

```
 Console.WriteLine("This message will show up in logcat output");
```

Nothing fancy.

Myself, I am looking for NLog target to output my logging to the logcat but the Console target doesn't appear to do so.